snap causes the shell to freeze upon login
Since the past 2~3 days I'm experiencing a bad slowdown when I login in 22.04.4.
I have HWE enabled and using Nvidia 550.54.14 (latest Stable binaries - installed via Proprietary GPU Drivers  ppa)
The output of dmesg is quite telling, and the interval between 9 and 16 seconds is approximately my experience of 'stuck' time with the gnome UI (please note I've always had the nvidia modeset errors at the end).
[    9.146934] rfkill: input handler disabled
[    9.844813] igb 0000:08:00.0 enp8s0: igb: enp8s0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
[   16.114188] kauditd_printk_skb: 89 callbacks suppressed
[   16.114191] audit: type=1400 audit(1712125860.060:100): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" class="cap" profile="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=2844 comm="snap-confine" capability=12  capname="net_admin"
[   16.114197] audit: type=1400 audit(1712125860.060:101): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" class="cap" profile="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=2844 comm="snap-confine" capability=38  capname="perfmon"
[   16.194249] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   16.194255] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   16.194259] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   16.500417] rfkill: input handler enabled
[   16.757563] usb 5-1: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[   18.233844] rfkill: input handler disabled
[   18.258517] audit: type=1400 audit(1712125862.204:102): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" class="cap" profile="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=3344 comm="snap-confine" capability=12  capname="net_admin"
[   18.258528] audit: type=1400 audit(1712125862.204:103): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" class="cap" profile="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=3344 comm="snap-confine" capability=38  capname="perfmon"
[   18.386970] warning: `kdeconnectd' uses wireless extensions which will stop working for Wi-Fi 7 hardware; use nl80211
[   18.454209] audit: type=1400 audit(1712125862.400:104): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" class="cap" profile="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=3456 comm="snap-confine" capability=12  capname="net_admin"
[   18.454222] audit: type=1400 audit(1712125862.400:105): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" class="cap" profile="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=3456 comm="snap-confine" capability=38  capname="perfmon"
[   18.535374] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000e00] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   19.043168] audit: type=1107 audit(1712125862.988:106): pid=1457 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.5" pid=3344 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=1472 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[   19.043473] audit: type=1107 audit(1712125862.988:107): pid=1457 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority" member="CheckAuthorization" mask="send" name=":1.5" pid=3344 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=1472 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[   19.045188] audit: type=1107 audit(1712125862.992:108): pid=1457 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.5" pid=3344 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=1472 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[   19.045351] audit: type=1107 audit(1712125862.992:109): pid=1457 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority" member="CheckAuthorization" mask="send" name=":1.5" pid=3344 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=1472 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[   20.020929] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000e00] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   20.021003] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000e00] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   20.021053] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000e00] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   20.021099] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000e00] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   20.039781] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000e00] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   20.039839] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000e00] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   20.039886] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000e00] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   20.039931] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000e00] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   20.073323] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000e00] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   20.073380] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000e00] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   20.073424] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000e00] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   20.073467] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000e00] Failed to grab modeset ownership

What shall I do next? Completely remove snap and see if the slowness goes away? Is it an issue with snap store specifically perhaps? Or snap in general? This is happening on an LTS - Perhaps I should abandon Ubuntu after 16+ years?
Edit - seems like snap apps keep on having issues with apparmor and block my gnome UI...
[   20.073467] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000e00] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[  266.613145] kauditd_printk_skb: 1 callbacks suppressed
[  266.613148] audit: type=1400 audit(1712126110.334:111): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap-update-ns.firefox" name="/usr/local/share/" pid=5087 comm="5" reques
ted_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[  266.618778] audit: type=1400 audit(1712126110.342:112): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap-update-ns.firefox" name="/var/lib/" pid=5087 comm="5" requested_mask
="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[  266.619153] audit: type=1400 audit(1712126110.342:113): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap-update-ns.firefox" name="/var/lib/" pid=5087 comm="5" requested_mask
="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[  266.946131] audit: type=1400 audit(1712126110.666:114): apparmor="DENIED" operation="symlink" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/dev/char/195:255" pid=5169 comm="glxtest"
 requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[  266.947868] audit: type=1400 audit(1712126110.670:115): apparmor="DENIED" operation="symlink" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/dev/char/195:0" pid=5169 comm="glxtest" r
equested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[  266.947939] audit: type=1400 audit(1712126110.670:116): apparmor="DENIED" operation="symlink" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/dev/char/195:0" pid=5169 comm="glxtest" r
equested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[  266.948058] audit: type=1400 audit(1712126110.670:117): apparmor="DENIED" operation="symlink" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/dev/char/195:0" pid=5169 comm="glxtest" r
equested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[  266.948173] audit: type=1400 audit(1712126110.670:118): apparmor="DENIED" operation="symlink" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/dev/char/195:0" pid=5169 comm="glxtest" r
equested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[  266.949436] audit: type=1400 audit(1712126110.670:119): apparmor="DENIED" operation="symlink" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/dev/char/195:255" pid=5169 comm="glxtest"
 requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[  266.949543] audit: type=1400 audit(1712126110.670:120): apparmor="DENIED" operation="symlink" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/dev/char/195:254" pid=5169 comm="glxtest" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[  308.257923] kauditd_printk_skb: 18 callbacks suppressed
[  308.257927] audit: type=1107 audit(1712126151.983:139): pid=1457 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/timedate1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.156" pid=5067 label="snap.firefox.firefox" peer_pid=5912 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[  309.318389] loop33: detected capacity change from 0 to 26472
[  309.712187] audit: type=1400 audit(1712126153.435:140): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="/snap/snapd/21184/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=6274 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  309.712196] audit: type=1400 audit(1712126153.435:141): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="/snap/snapd/21184/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper" pid=6274 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  309.946786] audit: type=1400 audit(1712126153.671:142): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.snap-store.hook.configure" pid=6278 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  310.209264] audit: type=1400 audit(1712126153.935:143): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" pid=6280 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  310.210764] audit: type=1400 audit(1712126153.935:144): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.snap-store.snap-store" pid=6279 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  310.236851] audit: type=1400 audit(1712126153.959:145): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software-local-file" pid=6281 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  310.689415] audit: type=1400 audit(1712126154.415:146): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap-update-ns.snap-store" pid=6277 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 1354.275646] audit: type=1400 audit(1712127198.025:147): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" class="cap" profile="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=8458 comm="snap-confine" capability=12  capname="net_admin"
[ 1354.275653] audit: type=1400 audit(1712127198.025:148): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" class="cap" profile="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=8458 comm="snap-confine" capability=38  capname="perfmon"
[ 1354.438438] audit: type=1400 audit(1712127198.185:149): apparmor="DENIED" operation="symlink" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/dev/char/195:255" pid=8549 comm="glxtest" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[ 1354.438599] audit: type=1400 audit(1712127198.185:150): apparmor="DENIED" operation="symlink" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/dev/char/195:0" pid=8549 comm="glxtest" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[ 1354.438668] audit: type=1400 audit(1712127198.185:151): apparmor="DENIED" operation="symlink" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/dev/char/195:0" pid=8549 comm="glxtest" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[ 1354.438785] audit: type=1400 audit(1712127198.185:152): apparmor="DENIED" operation="symlink" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/dev/char/195:0" pid=8549 comm="glxtest" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[ 1354.438912] audit: type=1400 audit(1712127198.189:153): apparmor="DENIED" operation="symlink" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/dev/char/195:0" pid=8549 comm="glxtest" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[ 1354.440300] audit: type=1400 audit(1712127198.189:154): apparmor="DENIED" operation="symlink" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/dev/char/195:255" pid=8549 comm="glxtest" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[ 1354.440434] audit: type=1400 audit(1712127198.189:155): apparmor="DENIED" operation="symlink" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/dev/char/195:254" pid=8549 comm="glxtest" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[ 1354.440493] audit: type=1400 audit(1712127198.189:156): apparmor="DENIED" operation="symlink" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/dev/char/195:0" pid=8549 comm="glxtest" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[ 1360.543146] rfkill: input handler enabled
[ 1361.906161] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000e00] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[ 1362.650837] rfkill: input handler disabled
[ 1370.450052] rfkill: input handler disabled
[ 1370.701264] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000e00] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[ 1372.183502] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000e00] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[ 1372.183580] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000e00] Failed to grab modeset ownership

Adding more evidence, looks like Firefox snap is trin to access /etc/fstab . Why?!?!
[ 5566.107612] audit: type=1400 audit(1712302387.753:203): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/etc/fstab" pid=6762 comm="firefox" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[ 5566.145003] audit: type=1400 audit(1712302387.793:204): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/home/ema/Downloads/ubuntu-22.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso" pid=6762 comm="pool-firefox-be" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=64055
[ 5566.248740] audit: type=1107 audit(1712302387.897:205): pid=1332 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/hostname1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.781" pid=6762 label="snap.firefox.firefox" peer_pid=19705 peer_label="unconfined" exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[ 5566.249878] audit: type=1107 audit(1712302387.897:206): pid=1332 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/hostname1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.781" pid=6762 label="snap.firefox.firefox" peer_pid=19705 peer_label="unconfined" exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[ 5702.337389] audit: type=1107 audit(1712302523.989:207): pid=1332 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.19" mask="receive" pid=6762 label="snap.firefox.firefox" peer_pid=1551 peer_label="unconfined" exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[ 5702.815941] audit: type=1107 audit(1712302524.465:208): pid=1332 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.19" mask="receive" pid=6762 label="snap.firefox.firefox" peer_pid=1551 peer_label="unconfined" exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[ 6284.717835] audit: type=1107 audit(1712303106.387:209): pid=1332 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.19" mask="receive" pid=6762 label="snap.firefox.firefox" peer_pid=1551 peer_label="unconfined" exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[ 6943.444220] audit: type=1107 audit(1712303765.136:210): pid=1332 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.19" mask="receive" pid=6762 label="snap.firefox.firefox" peer_pid=1551 peer_label="unconfined" exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'

This has caused a short further freeze.
Adding more evidence of my desktop enviornment resetting likly because of snap app being blocked by apparmor:
[   22.188245] audit: type=1400 audit(1714109480.140:99): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" class="cap" profile="/snap/snapd/21465/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=3540 comm="snap-confine" capability=12  capname="net_admin"
[   22.188260] audit: type=1400 audit(1714109480.140:100): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" class="cap" profile="/snap/snapd/21465/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=3540 comm="snap-confine" capability=38  capname="perfmon"
[   22.202813] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000e00] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   22.270619] audit: type=1400 audit(1714109480.220:101): apparmor="DENIED" operation="symlink" class="file" profile="snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration" name="/dev/char/195:255" pid=3612 comm="snapd-desktop-i" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[   22.272070] audit: type=1400 audit(1714109480.220:102): apparmor="DENIED" operation="symlink" class="file" profile="snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration" name="/dev/char/195:0" pid=3612 comm="snapd-desktop-i" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[   22.272188] audit: type=1400 audit(1714109480.220:103): apparmor="DENIED" operation="symlink" class="file" profile="snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration" name="/dev/char/195:0" pid=3612 comm="snapd-desktop-i" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[   22.272336] audit: type=1400 audit(1714109480.224:104): apparmor="DENIED" operation="symlink" class="file" profile="snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration" name="/dev/char/195:0" pid=3612 comm="snapd-desktop-i" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[   22.272466] audit: type=1400 audit(1714109480.224:105): apparmor="DENIED" operation="symlink" class="file" profile="snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration" name="/dev/char/195:0" pid=3612 comm="snapd-desktop-i" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[   22.276113] audit: type=1400 audit(1714109480.224:106): apparmor="DENIED" operation="symlink" class="file" profile="snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration" name="/dev/char/195:255" pid=3612 comm="snapd-desktop-i" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000


I guess that's wrong thinking. snapd itself cannot block the desktop environment, as it is not related at all to loading or providing the desktop environment.  Especially as named snaps like snap store and Firefox cannot run without being logged in and having a running graphics environment like Wayland or Xorg. That is also why, as you correctly say, snapd can be uninstalled without affecting the DE.
If your UI is slow and you installed a new video driver, IMHO the new video driver is the suspicious software to dive deeper in.

The issue happens with the previous stable driver, 535 as well. I've also run memtest86 and RAM seems ok. The errors I get in dmesg seem to be anecdotally at the same time when gnome shell freezes...

I know it's silly but, what happens if you mount ubuntu in a USB key and try to use it without installing? Does it still freeze? If not, would it be a problem to back things up and re-install everything?

I can confirm I've had other episodes, and dmesg alongside journalctl clearly shows snap applications being blocked by apparmor then breaking my desktop UI and making it sluggish. I will try a bootable USB stick soon.
